# Store data in hindi and other languages in django model

Tags: django, django-models

How can i store data in hindi and other languages in django-model? What django-field should i use in this case?

I'm storing data in hindi in Django TextField which is giving an error.

i.e.

```
class feedsMapping(models.Model) :
feeddescription = models.TextField('article description')
def __str__(self): 
        return ""
```

Comment: whats the error you are getting,make sure your field is utf8_general_ci

Comment: I'm getting below error : 
Incorrect string value: '\xE0\xA4\x86\xE0\xA4\xAA' for column.

Comment: It should work out of the box on modern databases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with encoding the field.Use utf8_general_ci which is international encoding standard which supports various symbol and languages.Go to your database,if your using MySQL(phpmyadmin) change collation to utf8_general_ci for that field.

This will fix the error.

Comment: Thanks for answering!

Can we set this in django-model instead mysql db?

Comment: That you need to research,or you could create a script which will modify all entries in DB.If i have that code,i will post along with the answer

Comment: Please share that code to change collation to utf8_general_ci in django model since I don't need to change it in mysql db.